# BouncyCastle EncryptAndSign not signing properly

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I have limited knowledge with PGP but came across code to use BouncyCastle to take care of it. I'm able to Encrypt/Decrypt a file but was asked to send an Encrypted and Signed file to an external vendor. When I use the following code I've found it does encrypt the file but when the vendor tries to decrypt they are getting an error `gpg: Can't check signature: No public key`. I don't know enough about PGP to know how to troubleshoot this properly. Looking for any suggestions to try.

Here is the code I'm using. The source and encrypted file path seem to be fine. The Public Key is pointing to the vendor's Public Key they provided me. The Private Key and Private Key Phrase are the Private Key file and password from the Key that I made for my company.

```
PGPEncryptDecrypt.EncryptAndSign(sourceFileFullPath,
                              encryptedFileFullPath,
                              publicKeyFileName, 
                              privateKeyFileName, 
                              privateKeyPhrase, 
                              true);
```

This is the code in the PGPEncryptDecrypt class I pulled from an example.

```
#region Encrypt and Sign
               

        public static void EncryptAndSign(string inputFile, string outputFile, string publicKeyFile, string privateKeyFile, string passPhrase, bool armor)
        {
            PGPEncryptionKeys encryptionKeys = new PGPEncryptionKeys(publicKeyFile, privateKeyFile, passPhrase);

            if (!File.Exists(inputFile))
                throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("Input file [{0}] does not exist.", inputFile));

            if (!File.Exists(publicKeyFile))
                throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("Public Key file [{0}] does not exist.", publicKeyFile));

            if (!File.Exists(privateKeyFile))
                throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("Private Key file [{0}] does not exist.", privateKeyFile));

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(passPhrase))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid Pass Phrase.");

            if (encryptionKeys == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Encryption Key not found.");

            using (Stream outputStream = File.Create(outputFile))
            {
                if (armor)
                    using (ArmoredOutputStream armoredOutputStream = new ArmoredOutputStream(outputStream))
                    {
                        OutputEncrypted(inputFile, armoredOutputStream, encryptionKeys);
                    }
                else
                    OutputEncrypted(inputFile, outputStream, encryptionKeys);
            }
        }

        private static void OutputEncrypted(string inputFile, Stream outputStream, PGPEncryptionKeys encryptionKeys)
        {
            using (Stream encryptedOut = ChainEncryptedOut(outputStream, encryptionKeys))
            {
                FileInfo unencryptedFileInfo = new FileInfo(inputFile);
                using (Stream compressedOut = ChainCompressedOut(encryptedOut))
                {
                    PgpSignatureGenerator signatureGenerator = InitSignatureGenerator(compressedOut, encryptionKeys);
                    using (Stream literalOut = ChainLiteralOut(compressedOut, unencryptedFileInfo))
                    {
                        using (FileStream inputFileStream = unencryptedFileInfo.OpenRead())
                        {
                            WriteOutputAndSign(compressedOut, literalOut, inputFileStream, signatureGenerator);
                            inputFileStream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void WriteOutputAndSign(Stream compressedOut, Stream literalOut, FileStream inputFile, PgpSignatureGenerator signatureGenerator)
        {
            int length = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[BufferSize];
            while ((length = inputFile.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
            {
                literalOut.Write(buf, 0, length);
                signatureGenerator.Update(buf, 0, length);
            }
            signatureGenerator.Generate().Encode(compressedOut);
        }

        private static Stream ChainEncryptedOut(Stream outputStream, PGPEncryptionKeys m_encryptionKeys)
        {
            PgpEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator;
            encryptedDataGenerator = new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.TripleDes, new SecureRandom());
            encryptedDataGenerator.AddMethod(m_encryptionKeys.PublicKey);
            return encryptedDataGenerator.Open(outputStream, new byte[BufferSize]);
        }

        private static Stream ChainCompressedOut(Stream encryptedOut)
        {
            PgpCompressedDataGenerator compressedDataGenerator = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(CompressionAlgorithmTag.Zip);
            return compressedDataGenerator.Open(encryptedOut);
        }

        private static Stream ChainLiteralOut(Stream compressedOut, FileInfo file)
        {
            PgpLiteralDataGenerator pgpLiteralDataGenerator = new PgpLiteralDataGenerator();
            return pgpLiteralDataGenerator.Open(compressedOut, PgpLiteralData.Binary, file);
        }

        private static PgpSignatureGenerator InitSignatureGenerator(Stream compressedOut, PGPEncryptionKeys m_encryptionKeys)
        {
            const bool IsCritical = false;
            const bool IsNested = false;
            PublicKeyAlgorithmTag tag = m_encryptionKeys.SecretKey.PublicKey.Algorithm;
            PgpSignatureGenerator pgpSignatureGenerator = new PgpSignatureGenerator(tag, HashAlgorithmTag.Sha1);
            pgpSignatureGenerator.InitSign(PgpSignature.BinaryDocument, m_encryptionKeys.PrivateKey);
            foreach (string userId in m_encryptionKeys.SecretKey.PublicKey.GetUserIds())
            {
                PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator subPacketGenerator = new PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
                subPacketGenerator.SetSignerUserId(IsCritical, userId);
                pgpSignatureGenerator.SetHashedSubpackets(subPacketGenerator.Generate());
                // Just the first one!
                break;
            }
            pgpSignatureGenerator.GenerateOnePassVersion(IsNested).Encode(compressedOut);
            return pgpSignatureGenerator;
        }

        #endregion Encrypt and Sign
```

**NEW ERROR AFTER INITIAL FIX**

I was able to get by the initial error of the signature check (we had the wrong keys) but now the vendor is getting the following error. Keep in mind that just Encrypting the file works but EncryptAndSign is what is giving the error. Anyone have another suggestions?

```
gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected
gpg: Hint: If this message was created before the year 2003 it is
     likely that this message is legitimate.  This is because back
     then integrity protection was not widely used.
gpg: Use the option '--ignore-mdc-error' to decrypt anyway.
gpg: decryption forced to fail!
```

Comment: "Can't check signature: No public key" - the recipient needs (and needs to trust) the public part of the key that the signature was generated with. This doesn't mean there's anything wrong with the signature generated: they just need to import your public key into their keyring.

Comment: I sent him my Public Key and he says he imported but I can have them try to re-confirm if it sounds like the issue. Just double checking, the Pubic Key I'm sending in to the function is their Public Key which is used for the encryption piece...correct? I wouldn't make sense to use my Public Key sense I'm passing in my Private Key.

Comment: I don't know the API, but yes: you need the public keys of all the recipients who can decrypt the encrypted data, and you need the private key of the signer.

Comment: I got past the initial error but still not able to get a complete decryption. I added more info to the initial post. Looking for any suggestions on what to check.